# Unlock a feature in App A if App B is installed

Tags: ios, keychain

I have two iOS applications say **App A** and **App B**. I need to implement a feature like follows:

If user is installed my **App A**, then I need to ask user to install my **App B** (if not installed) to unlock a special feature in **App A**.

**My issues:**

- How to find my App B is installed or not ?
- If **App B** is installed how to unlock a feature in **App A** ?
- Can I share the data through Keychain ?

**What I tried:**

- I searched alot but couldn't find any tutorials or sample codes
- Checked apple documentation but couldn't get any options
- I saw a similar functionality in [Talking Ginger](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/talking-ginger/id531323947?mt=8) application. It asks to install another application from similar company to get extra credits.

I think there is someway to do this without using private frameworks because the above mentioned apps are approved by apple and available in app store.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use iOS URL Schema `canOpenURL`. Using Url schema you can find an application is installed or not.

```
UIApplication *myApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *myPath = @"appURL://";
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myPath];
if ([myApplication canOpenURL:myURL]) {
    //Installed
    //Go for unlock login
}
else {
    //Not Installed
    //Inform user application not installed and redirect to iTunes Application url 
}
```

Comment: same as my answer, totally acceptable and ok for the store (AFAIK) :)

Comment: I know that, but forgot at the time I needed it :p

Answer (score 3):

There is a way by reading a plist thats.. technically possible but will get your apps rejected if found (well... might... depends on apple's mood)

better and safe is to use a custom URL scheme:
http://danielamitay.com/blog/2011/2/16/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps